# explanation of iterator in For loop that iterates over a function() ? ---and the lambda function as used in the example

Tags: loops, for-loop, lambda, iterator

This came from an [article](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/) describing common 'gotchas' in Python.  My question is not about the gotcha he's describing or why this code below doesn't do what you might expect --it is more basic than that.

I do not understand what the iterator over the function is doing:  The code is below;

there is a function:

```
def create_multiplers():
    return [lambda x: i*x for i in range(5)]
```

then, there is a for loop that iterates over the function:

```
for multiplier in create_multipliers():
print(multiplier(2))
```

1. what does the for loop do "in words"?  What does it mean to iterate over the function create_mutipliers?  How does that tell it how many times to loop?

I'm thinking it calls create_multipliers once, and the function returns the lambda function.  It is the lambda function loop that iterates 5 times --is that right?

2. How does multiplier(2)  pass the value to x in the lambda function -- how is it that mutlipiers(2) leads to `lambda 2: i*2 for i in range(5)`?

The combination of the for loop iterating over a function and the functionality of the returned lambda function is really confusing me.  There's some implicit stuff here I just don't get (I am an intermediate Python user).   I would appreciate a description of the execution of the code "in words".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop is not iterating over the function, it is iterating over the list of `lambda` functions returned by `create_multipliers`.  The tricky part is that return statement in `create_multipliers` is actually a list comprehension creating a list of (5) lambda expressions.  You can see that by looking at that this example code in isolation:

```
print([lambda x: i*x for i in range(5)])
```

Outputs:

```
[<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x0E9F0198>, <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x0E9F0150>, <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x0E9F0108>, <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x0E9F04F8>, <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x0E9F0540>]
```

The `lambda` functions take a single parameter `x`, and each pass through your `for` loop is invoking a `lambda` function in the list of `lambda` functions returned by `create_multipliers` and passing the value of 2 in as `x`.

Comment: thank you. So, the for loop statement calls `create_multipliers()`. and that function returns a list of 5 lambda functions.  somehow, now the  iterator, multiplier,  iterates through these--I don't understand how it knows to do this.....and morevover, how multiplier(2) passes 2 to x in the lambda function.  Can you please walk me through that?

Comment: Right, so now that you see that `create_multiplers()` returns a list, the `for multiplier` statement is simply iterating over that list in typical Python fashion.  What does `multiplier` evaluate to when called in the `print` statement?  Well, it evaluates to a lambda (nameless) function because that is what was in the list returned by `create_multipliers()`. To learn more about lambda functions, check out [this article](https://stackabuse.com/lambda-functions-in-python/).